Reverse text by rgx notepad++
This is my text And I want it to be changed with the desired sign or word that I put between the text
hello my name $ is alex jef
I want it to be like this
is alex jef $ hello my name
I test this:
Find what: (.*) \(\$\) (.*)
Replace with: $2 (\$) $1

^(.*) \$ (.*)$ replace it with $2 \$ $1 or ([^$]*) \$ ([^$]*) replace it with $2 \$ $1?

Dear friend How about this?                          my $ name  is $ alex jef                                alex jef $ name is $ my

Case 1

hello my name $ is alex jef

You can use:
^(.*) \$ (.*)$

and replace it with
$2 \$ $1

or use
([^$]*) \$ ([^$]*)

and replace it with
$2 \$ $1


Case 2
For these test cases
my $ name is $ alex jef

You can use:
([^$]*) \$ ([^$]*) \$ ([^$]*)

and replace it with
$3 \$ $2 \$ $1


Notes:

If you think it is necessary, you can add ^ and $ anchors to the expression, which limits this to lines only.

^([^$]*) \$ ([^$]*) \$ ([^$]*)$

General Case

If you had more groups, you can simply add more groups here:

([^$]*) \$ ([^$]*) \$ ([^$]*) .... ([^$]*) \$ ([^$]*) \$ ([^$]*)


and replace it with:
($n) \$ ($n - 1) \$ ($n - 2) .... ($3) \$ ($2) \$ ($1)



Nice thank all good work

Hello, dear friend, this is working properly, now I have a problem, when a line is empty, half of the text is lowered, how can I limit it so that it only works in one line?

@omidleon Ask a new question, add sample inputs and expected outputs, then send me the link I'll answer it. I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish.
